# TFX StatisticsGen for image data

Tags: tensorflow, tfx

Hi I've trying to get a TFX Pipeline going just as an exercise really. I'm using `ImportExampleGen` to load `TFRecords` from disk. Each `Example` in the `TFRecord` contains a jpg in the form of a byte string, height, width, depth, steering and throttle labels.

I'm trying to use `StatisticsGen` but I'm receiving this warning;
`WARNING:root:Feature "image_raw" has bytes value "None" which cannot be decoded as a UTF-8 string.` and crashing my Colab Notebook. As far as I can tell all the byte-string images in the TFRecord are not corrupt.

I cannot find concrete examples on `StatisticsGen` and handling image data. According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/data_validation/get_started#computing_descriptive_data_statistics) Tensorflow Data Validation can deal with image data.

> In addition to computing a default set of data statistics, TFDV can also compute statistics for semantic domains (e.g., images, text). To enable computation of semantic domain statistics, pass a tfdv.StatsOptions object with enable_semantic_domain_stats set to True to tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord.

But I'm not sure how this fits in with `StatisticsGen`.

Here is the code that instantiates an `ImportExampleGen` then the `StatisticsGen`

```py
from tfx.utils.dsl_utils import tfrecord_input
from tfx.components.example_gen.import_example_gen.component import ImportExampleGen
from  tfx.proto import example_gen_pb2

examples = tfrecord_input(_tf_record_dir)
# https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/examplegen#custom_inputoutput_split
# has a good explanation of splitting the data the 'output_config' param

# Input train split is _tf_record_dir/*'
# Output 2 splits: train:eval=8:2.
train_ratio = 8
eval_ratio  = 10-train_ratio
output = example_gen_pb2.Output(
             split_config=example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig(splits=[
                 example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='train',
                                                   hash_buckets=train_ratio),
                 example_gen_pb2.SplitConfig.Split(name='eval',
                                                   hash_buckets=eval_ratio)
             ]))
example_gen = ImportExampleGen(input=examples,
                               output_config=output)
context.run(example_gen)

statistics_gen = StatisticsGen(
    examples=example_gen.outputs['examples'])
context.run(statistics_gen)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update:
I have been doing some digging. The [TFX StatisticsGen Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/api_docs/python/tfx/components/StatisticsGen#class_statisticsgen) leans on [tfx.data_validation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/guide/tfdv) which lead me to try this; `stats = tfdv.generate_statistics_from_tfrecord(data_location=tfrecords_filename)` which results in the same warning s and crashing of Colab. Getting closet to the root of the issue I guess.

Comment: Hmmmm ok, so I found a CIFAR 10 [example](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/tree/master/tfx/examples/cifar10) where a tfrecord has been created already. When I use it to create a StatisticsGen I get the same warning and my Google Colab crashed. Maybe it's just Colab getting overwhelmed with text output. Maybe I can change the log level. See if that helps.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution to this issue? I have the same error message.

Comment: Had a similar issue, the fix was to update to tfx 21.2, that got things working interactively in a notebook as above. Updating to 21.2 also got things working running on kubeflow (make sure to update your dockerfile i've adapted this example similarly to above to use ImportExampleGen https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/blob/master/tfx/examples/chicago_taxi_pipeline/taxi_pipeline_interactive.ipynb)

Comment: Thanks @DarrenBrien. I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: So there seems to be an issue with TFX and Colab at the moment. I am unable to even run the standard tfx components.ipynb. I have raised an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/1595). Will try again when the issue is resolved.

Comment: Sad times @DarrenBrien. Even with `tfx==0.21.2` I still a bazillion `Warnings` then my  Colab tab becomes unresponsive. I'm going to try to figure out how to change the log level so the cell output doesn't spam me with warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [git issue response](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/1622#issuecomment-616755799)
Thanks [Evan Rosen](https://github.com/embr)

Hi Folks,

The warnings you are seeing indicate that StatisticsGen is trying to treat your raw image features like a categorical string feature. The image bytes are being decoded just fine. The issue is that when the stats (including top K examples) are being written, the output proto is expecting a UTF-8 valid string, but instead gets the raw image bytes. Nothing is wrong with your setups from what I can tell, but this is just an unintended side-effect of a well-intentioned warning in the event that you have a categorical string feature which can't be serialized. We'll look into finding a better default that handles image data more elegantly.

In the meantime, to tell StatisticsGen that this feature is really an opaque blob, you can pass in a user-modified schema as described in the StatsGen docs. To generate this schema, you can run StatisticsGen and SchemaGen once (on a sample of data) and then modify the inferred schema to annotate that image features. Here is a modified version of the colab from @tall-josh:

[Open In Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/embr/3827b641d8afc915ce1545a9956cc107/copy-of-tfx-dingocar.ipynb)

The additional steps are a bit verbose, but having a curated schema is often a good practice for other reasons. Here is the cell that I added to the notebook:

```py
from google.protobuf import text_format
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from tensorflow_metadata.proto.v0 import schema_pb2

# Load autogenerated schema (using stats from small batch)

schema = tfx.utils.io_utils.SchemaReader().read(
    tfx.utils.io_utils.get_only_uri_in_dir(
        tfx.types.artifact_utils.get_single_uri(schema_gen.outputs['schema'].get())))

# Modify schema to indicate which string features are images.
# Ideally you would persist a golden version of this schema somewhere rather
# than regenerating it on every run.
for feature in schema.feature:
  if feature.name == 'image/raw':
    feature.image_domain.SetInParent()

# Write modified schema to local file
user_schema_dir ='/tmp/user-schema/'
tfx.utils.io_utils.write_pbtxt_file(
    os.path.join(user_schema_dir, 'schema.pbtxt'), schema)

# Create ImportNode to make modified schema available to other components
user_schema_importer = tfx.components.ImporterNode(
    instance_name='import_user_schema',
    source_uri=user_schema_dir,
    artifact_type=tfx.types.standard_artifacts.Schema)

# Run the user schema ImportNode
context.run(user_schema_importer)
```

Hopefully you find this workaround is useful. In the meantime, we'll take a look at a better default experience for image-valued features.

Answer (score 1):

Groked this and found the solution to be dramatically simpler than i thought...

```
from tfx.orchestration.experimental.interactive.interactive_context import InteractiveContext
import logging
...
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
...
context = InteractiveContext(pipeline_name='my_pipe')
...
c = StatisticsGen(...)
...
context.run(c)
```

Comment: Thanks [@DarrenBrien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5873699/darren-brien). That worked in the sense that I can continue running the notebook without overwhelming the cell output with warning messages. Ideally, we'll figure out how to properly encode/decode image data so the warning is never triggered. 

I have posted an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfx/issues/1622) surrounding how to correctly encode/decode image data so StatisticsGen actually works.

Comment: For anyone interested [Run in Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/github/tall-josh/tfx-dingocar/blob/git-issue/TFX_dingocar.ipynb). Run everything down to the **StatisticeGen** Cells